# Laravel - how to launch emails dynamically by tenant

Tags: php, laravel

I'm making an api in Laravel, where my registered users are segmented by tenant, but when I send the welcome email, each tenent has their own domain. That is, when a user registers with tenant1, I want to welcome them to no-reply@tenat1.com.

But in laravel I put the email information in the .env:

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_Host=mail.propnex.sg
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=no-reply@tenant1.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=xxxxxxxx
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=ssl
```

how do I pass this information that I'm passing in .env, dynamically?

Comment: See [Configuring The Sender](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/mail#configuring-the-sender).

Comment: Are you trying to use a different email _account_ for each tenant? Or just a different sender address for the welcome email?

Comment: the email will be different, I saw that in the documentation I can pass the from, but I would have to pass the password too, and I didn't see how to do it.

Comment: I think you can change config values on the fly before send each email. Ie: `config([
    'mail.driver' => 'smtp',
    'mail.host' => 'mail.propnex.sg',
    'mail.port' => 587,
    'mail.encryption' => 'ssl',
    'mail.username' => 'no-reply@tenantyyy.com',
    'mail.password' => 'yyyyyyyy',
]);`

Comment: I'll try, thank you very much @porloscerrosΨ

Comment: `MAIL_USERNAME` is the userid of the account you're authenticating against the remote SMTP server with. You should not be changing it or specifying a different value at runtime. If you do, your authentication will fail, and you won't be able to send anything. Instead, call `setFrom()`, `setSender()`, `setReplyTo()`, or `setReturnPath()`, as appropriate. Doing so will not require providing a new password.